# How to make the left column as navigator and right column as body?

Tags: html, css, iframe, layout

How to make the left column as navigator and right column as body?

```
<style>
    #leftBodyVideo{
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
}

#rightBodyVideo{
width: 45%;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div id="leftBodyVideo">
    <h5>Pyraminx ao12 16 46</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDN9BXLFGhg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<div id="rightBodyVideo">
    <h5>Lubing DaYan ZhanChi Cube</h5>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydg0APsB7IU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Expected result is like this (for documentation template): https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the `div` and use `overflow-y: scroll;`.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/72xbjdes/)

Here is the code:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/> 1
  <br/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add iframe `width` `100%`

```
iframe{width:100%; max-width:560px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kd1v21ad/1/